# Can I prevent NSDocument from saving window positions?

Tags: xcode, nswindow

I've looked through the NSDocuments docs but can't see any methods for controlling whether window positions are saved. But if I move a window before quitting, that position overrides the window position set in IB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

In your XIB file, select the window. You should see the options on the right of the screen.
The "Restorable" check box should be what you're looking for. I haven't tried this in a document based application but I'm pretty sure it's the same here.

Comment: Thanks, I should've seen that. ( I need 1 more rep, then I'll up-vote it)